# Joining two select queries to display the results in a single line from the same table

Tags: sql-server, join, select

Hopefully an easy one but I need help.

I have two queries looking at the same data but with different where statements.
The data shows value of different card brands from the days trading. however, each total is on a separate line so id like to see all on one line for a store
so [LOCATION], [TRADE DATE], [VISA],[AMEX],[# RECORDS].

I have limited the query to a single location for now.

Any help would be most appreciated

Query A (Visa records)

```
SELECT 
 TILLREADREQUEST.STRTRADECODE AS [LOCATION]  
,TILLREADREQUEST.DTMTRADEDATE AS [TRADE DATE]
,SUM(TILLREADDETAIL.CURVALUE) AS [VISA]
,COUNT(TILLREADREQUEST.ctrcode) AS [# RECORDS],

FROM          
 TILLREADDETAIL INNER JOIN
 TILLREADREQUEST ON TILLREADDETAIL.LINTREQUESTCODE = TILLREADREQUEST.CTRCODE
WHERE        (TILLREADDETAIL.INTTENDERCODE IN ('3')) and TILLREADREQUEST.DTMTRADEDATE > getdate()-2 AND STRTRADECODE = 'SHEFFIELD'
group by     TILLREADREQUEST.STRTRADECODE,TILLREADREQUEST.DTMTRADEDATE*
```

Query B (Amex Records)

```
SELECT 
 TILLREADREQUEST.STRTRADECODE AS [LOCATION]  
,TILLREADREQUEST.DTMTRADEDATE AS [TRADE DATE]
,SUM(TILLREADDETAIL.CURVALUE) AS [AMEX]


FROM          
 TILLREADDETAIL INNER JOIN
 TILLREADREQUEST ON TILLREADDETAIL.LINTREQUESTCODE = TILLREADREQUEST.CTRCODE
WHERE        (TILLREADDETAIL.INTTENDERCODE IN ('4')) and TILLREADREQUEST.DTMTRADEDATE > getdate()-2 AND STRTRADECODE = 'SHEFFIELD'
group by     TILLREADREQUEST.STRTRADECODE,TILLREADREQUEST.DTMTRADEDATE*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CASE`in your query for the particular condition:

```
SELECT 
 TILLREADREQUEST.STRTRADECODE AS [LOCATION]  
,TILLREADREQUEST.DTMTRADEDATE AS [TRADE DATE]
,SUM(CASE WHEN TILLREADDETAIL.INTTENDERCODE IN ('3')
   THEN TILLREADDETAIL.CURVALUE
   ELSE 0
   END
) AS [VISA]
,SUM(CASE WHEN TILLREADDETAIL.INTTENDERCODE IN ('4')
   THEN TILLREADDETAIL.CURVALUE
   ELSE 0
   END
) AS [AMEX]
,COUNT(TILLREADREQUEST.ctrcode) AS [# RECORDS],

FROM          
 TILLREADDETAIL INNER JOIN
 TILLREADREQUEST ON TILLREADDETAIL.LINTREQUESTCODE = TILLREADREQUEST.CTRCODE
WHERE        (TILLREADDETAIL.INTTENDERCODE IN ('3', '4')) and TILLREADREQUEST.DTMTRADEDATE > getdate()-2 AND STRTRADECODE = 'SHEFFIELD'
group by     TILLREADREQUEST.STRTRADECODE,TILLREADREQUEST.DTMTRADEDATE*
```

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to count records separately for VISA/AMEX then you'll have to add case there as well.

```
SELECT 
 TILLREADREQUEST.STRTRADECODE AS [LOCATION]  
,TILLREADREQUEST.DTMTRADEDATE AS [TRADE DATE]
,SUM(CASE WHEN TILLREADDETAIL.INTTENDERCODE IN ('3') THEN TILLREADDETAIL.CURVALUE ELSE 0 END) AS [VISA]
,SUM(CASE WHEN TILLREADDETAIL.INTTENDERCODE IN ('4') THEN TILLREADDETAIL.CURVALUE ELSE 0 END) AS [AMEX]
,COUNT(CASE WHEN TILLREADREQUEST.ctrcode = '3' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS [# RECORDS],
,COUNT(CASE WHEN TILLREADREQUEST.ctrcode = '4' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS [# RECORDS]
FROM          
 TILLREADDETAIL INNER JOIN
 TILLREADREQUEST ON TILLREADDETAIL.LINTREQUESTCODE = TILLREADREQUEST.CTRCODE
WHERE        (TILLREADDETAIL.INTTENDERCODE IN ('3','4')) and TILLREADREQUEST.DTMTRADEDATE > getdate()-2 AND STRTRADECODE = 'SHEFFIELD'
group by     TILLREADREQUEST.STRTRADECODE,TILLREADREQUEST.DTMTRADEDATE*
```